# HTTP POST upload from ios to specified server folder

Tags: php, ios, file-upload, ftp, server-side

I want to allow my ios app to upload a html file to a folder of my ubuntu server

Im sending http post from ios.
 I only ever want to upload, to this one folder on my server.

This is just a prototype of a feature which will not be available to the outside world so I have no security worries for now

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$target_dir = "/var/www/html/";
$postVar = $_POST['data'];
$target_file = $target_dir . basename(“test.html");

$fp = fopen($target_file, "w") or die("Couldn't open $target_file for writing!");
fwrite($fp, $postVar) or die("Couldn't write values to file!"); 

fclose($fp); 
echo "Saved to $file successfully!";

header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . basename($target_file));
?>
```

If the file is sent to the server from ios using http post, is there any more I need to do to recieve the file/ convert it back into a .html?  I believe I need the contents of the file body

The only response I get in xcode is "SharingTravelStories[2666:178049] Receipt of server response completed"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a relative path, try the absolute path... note the leading "/"

```
$target_dir = "/var/www/html"
```

Comment: If that was correct in the original code, make sure the user running the web service has write access to /var/www/html/ ...

Comment: I have changed the permissions so www-data has write access is that the idea?

Comment: That's a start... http://ss64.com/bash/chmod.html  and add error logging at the beginning of the php script with error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Ok and lastly I logged into webmin and ticket the execute permission, not sure if that needed doing

Comment: did you see any errors after you added the error logging at the start of the script?